# Eclipse camelcase python method name search

Tags: python, regex, eclipse

Currently doing some re-factoring and am trying to get a regex pattern that can return any method that is camel case.  I am going to be using the regex option in eclipse search files.

```
def thisIsATest(self):
    pass
def this_is_a_test(self):
    pass
def this(self):
    pass
```

I would want the search to obviously pick up `thisIsATest`

Comment: "regex pattern that can return any method that is not camel case [...] I would want the search to obviously pick up thisIsATest" - unless I'm reading your wrong, you contradict yourself. Please clarify.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Edit: Oops you wanted camel case... Fixed (again):

```
def\s+(?=[a-z]+(?:[A-Z][a-z0-9]+)*\s*\().*?\(
```

Edit: To exclude single words I use a `+` instead of a `*`.

```
def\s+(?=[a-z]+(?:[A-Z][a-z0-9]+)+\s*\().*?\(
```

Comment: Should that be [a-z] vs [a-Z] ?

Comment: @Nix.  just figured that out.  It's fixed now.

Comment: Is there a way to filter out single words?  ex: `def test(self)` ?

Comment: @Nix, my regex doesn't count `thisIsATest` because `A` is a single-letter word.  Is that a problem?

Comment: I would hope someone didn't use I / A in a method, so it probably wouldn't effect us.